# download file link produces 404 page

Tags: python, html

I am trying to create a link that allows a user to download a zip file that's been generated earlier in the python script.  The script then writes an HTML link to a web page.  The user should be able to click the link and download their zip file.

```
import os,sys
downloadZip = ("http://<server>/folder/structure/here/" + zipFileName + ".zip")
print """<h3><a href="{}" download>Download zip file</a></h3>""".format(downloadZip)
```

The result is a link that when clicked opens a 404 page.  I've noticed that on that page, it displays

```
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\inputted\path\here\file.zip
```

I am testing this on the same server the processing is occurring on.  I wouldn't think that should make a difference, but here I am.  The end result should be a zip file downloaded to the user's pc.

Comment: How are you serving up the files? Meaning what server program are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this would be helpful or not but I have noticed that some 'server package apps' disallow the execution/download of certain filetypes. I had a similar thing happen years ago.

To test if this is the case, create a new folder in your web directory and add an index.html page with some random writing (to identify that you have the correct page). Quickly try to access this page.

Next create a .zip file, put it in the same folder as the index.html file you just created, and add a Download link on the index.html page.

Now revisit the page, and try to download the file you created. If it works then there is a problem elsewhere, if it doesn't then whatever server package application you are using probably set Apache to block .zip files by default. Hope this helps buddy :)

Comment: You were exactly right.  As it happens, this server is a vm on a laptop.  I was able to just hit it from the browser outside the vm and prove your hypothesis.  Well played, sir.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the issue of allowing users to download a .zip file. It was working then stopped and started going to a 404 error page. I went back to the link and it was missing the www. I added this part to the url path and it downloaded correctly, as before.

Example: did not work: https://url path/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/filename.zip name

Did work: https://www.url path/wp-content/uploads/2023/03/filename.zip